# Shadowbox with links created via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, shadowbox

I'm working on a page which already successfully uses Shadowbox.js. There's a search link at the top of the page which looks like this:

```
<a href="/search/" rel="shadowbox;height=600;width=980" title="search flexsim.com" id="searchBoxLink">Search</a>
```

This is located in the header.

In the body of the page I can search for a user and load their account information via AJAX. The plan is to add a button to their information table so a system admin can edit it. I'd like to use Shadowbox to bring up a confirmation page once the admin has submitted the edits. I'm using this link to try to do so:

```
<a href="/account/createPopup.php" rel="shadowbox;height=600;width=800" title="Submit a note" class="something">Submit</a>
```

However, when I click this link, it navigates directly to createPopup.php instead of loading it in a Shadowbox.

Am I supposed to be doing something with Shadowbox in JavaScript so that it plays nicely with links loaded via AJAX?

Comment: After loading the links with ajax, you need to re initialize the shadowbox for these new elements.

Comment: From the Shadowbox usage page, I gather that I need to call Shadowbox.setup() for these new links. They also skip the initial setup. Can I allow the initial setup to happen, then call .setup() again for each new link? This approach hasn't worked for me when I call .setup() from the JavaScript console.

Comment: Yes, you can call the Shadowbox.setup(...) for the new links. You only need to set a more specific selector so that only the new links will be initialized